# Modifying hash function

Tags: c++, hash, xor, sha256

I need to modify hash code,so that instead of 256 hash value,I get 64 bit hash value following the rule that instead of 256 bit fromula.

```
h=A||B||C||D||E||F||G||H
```

where `A`, `B`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H` is 32 bit words, `||` concat operation. I must receive 64 bit hash with formula

```
 h=B xor D xor F xor H || A xor C xor E xor G.
```

I am using following Sha256 implementation but I am unable to find part where this has to be done-
http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function

Where sha should be something like

```
SHA-256("10301231030456") = 0xe4a6aade78b1c5ad21a76adca6beb75634c1ff45e7aba9d18f861211d43d69e1
```

the goal is to receive:

```
SHA-256-mod("10301231030456") = 0xed99b2cb7e462d56
```

Thank you

Comment: So what stops you from modifying this hash function? Read the code and then modify it appropriately.

Comment: So what's your question? How to xor few `uint32_t`s? Rather than modifying that function, call it and convert the output to what you need.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast your 256 bit array to `unsigned long mod_args[8];`

```
std::string sha = sha256("10301231030456");

char hash[32];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sha.length(); i += 2, j++)
{
    std::string sub = sha.substr(i, 2);
    hash[j] = strtoul(sub.c_str(), NULL, 16);
}

unsigned long mod_args[8];
memcpy(mod_args, hash, 32);
```

than getting 2 pieces of 64 bit:

```
unsigned long a = mod_args[1] ^ mod_args[3] ^ mod_args[5] ^ mod_args[7];
unsigned long b = mod_args[0] ^ mod_args[2] ^ mod_args[4] ^ mod_args[6];
```

than getting result by concat that two pieces

```
unsigned long long result = (((unsigned long long)a) << 32) | b;
```

or

```
unsigned long long result = (((unsigned long long)b) << 32) | a;
```

considering what piece of hash must be older `a` or `b`

the complete solution is:

```
#define B_OLDER_THAN_A

int main()
{
    std::string sha = sha256("10301231030456");

    char hash[32];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sha.length(); i += 2, j++)
    {
        std::string sub = sha.substr(i, 2);
        hash[j] = strtoul(sub.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    }

    unsigned long mod_args[8];
    memcpy(mod_args, hash, 32);

    unsigned long a = mod_args[1] ^ mod_args[3] ^ mod_args[5] ^ mod_args[7];
    unsigned long b = mod_args[0] ^ mod_args[2] ^ mod_args[4] ^ mod_args[6];

#ifdef B_OLDER_THAN_A
    unsigned long long result = (((unsigned long long)b) << 32) | ((unsigned long long)a);
#else
    unsigned long long result = (((unsigned long long)a) << 32) | ((unsigned long long)b);
#endif

    unsigned char output[8] = { 0 };

    memcpy(output, (char*)(&result), 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        std::cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (unsigned int)(output[i]);

    std::cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A violation of strict aliasing rule is punishable by two years of coding in Java.

Comment: @SergeyA: What you mean?

Comment: I mean that your code violates strict aliasing rule. And we do not want such code, we do not!

Comment: Right here: `unsigned long* mod_args = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(sha_result);`

Comment: @SergeyA: And what did you suggest?

Comment: I suggest not to violate such a rule.

Comment: @SergeyA: How I can do it?

Comment: Well, you are trying to answer a question, not ask one, right? If you want to **ask** a question, feel free to do so by clicking 'Ask Question' in the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: @SergeyA:  Did my answer satisfy your standards now ?

Comment: Well, you took my answer and copied-pasted it into yours. Do not expect an upvote from me for that.

Comment: @SergeyA:  This was the different question.

Comment: @SergeyA: And thank you for help! :)

Comment: no it dodnot work for me,but I got an idea form you
I made 8 substrings using .substr...and now problem is using xor operator on strings

Comment: @njok: so you also whant to diplay result value as string?

Comment: yes..
let say that 
string A=123fb
string B=234ac

I need string C that would be 31757

Comment: @njok: did you try to print result value? in hexadecimal mode

Comment: given number is in hex mode,what come out of hash function
only it does not have 0x at beggining...
I tried all kinds of string to hex and than xor..but nothing seems to work

Comment: @njok: i have found a typo in my code so a update it.

Comment: @njok: Are you sure that modified function must return `SHA-256-mod("10301231030456") = 0xed99b2cb7e462d56`?

Comment: I solve it on my on way,but without you I would'nt have made it
Thanks once more :D

Comment: @njok: Glad can help you! Good luck!)